# How to randomize an array, leaving the items that are the same far from each other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Basically I have an array where there are similar items close by, but I would like to find a way where I leave these items that are the same apart from each other ex:

```
var array = [1,2,3,3,4]; 

var myWishArray = [1,2,3,4,3];
||
var myWishArray = [3,2,3,4,1];
||
var myWishArray = [3,2,3,1,4];
...
```

Comment: please add some examples of the (un?)wanted divisions.

Comment: This article would problably help you - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-numbers-in-an-array-such-that-no-two-adjacent-numbers-are-same/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's enough that two equal numbers are never neighbors, then you can

- sort the list
- fill a new array with these numbers in two passes, leaving a space of one

```js
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4];
a.sort();
b = Array(a.length);
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
    if (i * 2 < a.length) {
        b[i * 2] = a[i];
    } else {
        start = i - Math.ceil(a.length / 2)
        b[start * 2 + 1] = a[i];
    }
}
console.log(b);
```